# Virtualbox AMD processor

Tags: virtualbox

I am using a custom-built PC with an *AMD FX 8350* CPU and an *ASUS M5A78LM USB 3* motherboard.

I want to run Ubuntu in Virtualbox.

However, last time I ran Ubuntu on my Asus Aspire, it fried my motherboard/CPU.

Is it safe to run Ubuntu 16.04 in VBox with AMD-V acceleration on windows 7?
I also have an GTX 980 in this machine, so I can't afford to damage my graphics card.

Comment: Software can't "burn your motherboard".

Comment: @Pilot6 - It is possible he meant that it overheated

Comment: Overheating is a hardware issue. A properly built computer will not burn even working with high loads. If the system is incorrectly built and has poor ventilation, then any software can burn it.

Comment: is it safe to run it on my PC's config ? just let me know that @Pilot6

Comment: It is safe on any config, including the one that has been burnt already.;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it is perfectly safe.**

If your computer isn't overheating in Windows, it won't overheat while running Vbox in Windows. (Assuming you've got a good CPU cooler).

If you are using the stock cooler, I highly recommend you go to your local Microcenter and pick up a Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO.

When you say the software "burnt your motherboard", did you meant that it overheated and the CPU was fried?

If so, that was probably caused by the fan not spinning at all. I experienced that issue on an Acer Aspire laptop, and the fix was to simply update the BIOS. After doing so, the fan worked normally and temps were fine.

Software ***alone*** cannot fry electronics. Prime 95 can't fry your CPU just by itself. The Motherboard/CPU can decide whether to thermal throttle or not. And it isn't Prime 95 that applies a vCore boost when running with AVX...

Comment: I would not be so sure that it is "perfectly safe" ;-) If OP thinks that VB "burnt their MB", it may happen again in their mind.

Comment: The fans were working properly and laptop was in good shape and then suddenly blue screen and bam..... and @Pilot6 I was not running VB on my laptop,i ran pure Ubuntu 14.04 on it when my MB fried.

Comment: And why do you think the "bam" happened because of VB?

Comment: @Fusionist this ^^^

Comment: @AndroidDev BTW software CAN burn electronics in many cases, thoug it shows poor electronics )))

Comment: @Pilot6 - I said software **alone** can't fry electronics. Prime 95 can't fry your CPU just by itself. The Motherboard/CPU can decide whether to thermal throttle or not.

Comment: Laptop BIOS should not be erased by an OS, but it used to be on Samsung laptops. And it was unfixable.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Huh? What does that have to do with anything?